# Syntax for Calling Method with Completion in Swift using Singleton Pattern

Tags: ios, singleton, closures

I am trying to call a method with a closure located in a separate class  by way of a Shared Instance.  Syntax that works to call the function from within the same class is not working when called from another class using the shared instance.

Here is the method in the utilities class:

```
 func findNearbyLocations(completion: @escaping (MKMapItem?, Error?) -> ())  {
//get location
}
```

This works to call it from within the class:

```
self.findNearbyLocations(query:val1!) {
        placemark, error in
        guard let placemark = placemark, error == nil else {
            return
        }
}
```

When I try to call it from another class, using the following, the compiler gives error:

> Extra argument 'query' in call

```
Utilities.shared.findNearbyLocations(query:val1!) {
           placemark, error in
           guard let placemark = placemark, error == nil else {
           return
       }
 }
```

I am able to call other methods using the shared instance without issue.  What could account for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current function should be called like this

```
Utilities.shared.findNearbyLocations { (placemark, error) in
           guard let placemark = placemark, error == nil else {
           return
       }
 }
```

If you need to send a parameter , then change function to

```
func findNearbyLocations(query:QueryType,completion: @escaping (MKMapItem?, Error?) -> ())  { --- }
```

Then you'll be able to do

```
Utilities.shared.findNearbyLocations(query:Your_Value) {  (placemark, error) in
           guard let placemark = placemark, error == nil else {
           return
       }
 }
```